# undefined variable in laravel view

Tags: php, html, laravel

This is my controller

```
public function document(){
    $file = File::paginate(6);
    return view('admin.document',compact('file'));
}
```

and this is my view

```
@foreach ($file as $key => $value )
<tr class="file{{$value->id}}">
    <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
    <td>{{$value->title}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->file}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->status}}</td> 
    <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm" data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-title="{{$value->title}}" data-status="{{$value->status}}">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-title="{{$value->title}}" data-status="{{$value->status}}">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-title="{{$value->title}}" data-status="{{$value->status}}">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </a>
    </td>  
@endforeach
```

I don't know why I'm getting error

Comment: which variable is undefined?

Comment: Can you copy paste the error message?

Comment: Note you're missing your closing `</tr>` (should be ok, most browsers know to handle missing tags, but missing regardless)

Comment: Can you share your error message and file table structure?

Comment: @Rockhopper "Undefined variable: file (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't see initialization of `$no` variable, but you use it in your blade template.

Answer (score 0):

Check the $no variable you are trying to use in the $no++

Answer (score 0):

Like some people noticed `$no` variable is the guilty one.

Instead of having a counter starting from Laravel 5.3 there is a new handy `$loop` variable. The $loop variable is a stdClass object that provides meta information about the loop you're currently inside. It exposes the following properties:

- **index:** the 0-based index of the current item in the loop; 0 would mean "first item"
- **iteration:** the 1-based index of the current item in the loop; 1 would mean "first item"
- **remaining:** how many items remain in the loop; if current item is first of three, would return 2
- **count:** the count of items in the loop
- **first:** boolean; whether this is the first item in the loop
- **last:** boolean; whether this is the last item in the loop
  depth: integer; how many "levels" deep this loop is; returns 1 for a loop, 2 for a loop within a loop, etc.
- **parent:** if this loop is within another @foreach loop, returns a reference to the $loop variable for the parent loop item; otherwise returns null

In your case you will need `$loop->iteration`.

```
<td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
```

Comment: $no is not the problem i didn't include this part of the code <?php $no=1; ?>

Answer (score 0):

> You got the error because: you do not define variable `$no` .
>
> Define as $no = 1 before the loop...
>
> Example:

```
@php($no = 1)
```

Comment: it's defined as <?php $no=1; ?> i didnt include that part in the code i uploaded earlier

Answer (score 0):

try this

your controller

```
public function document(){
   $data['file'] = File::paginate(6);
   return view('admin.document',$data);
}
```

foreach in your view

```
@foreach ($file as $value )
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
@php $no = 0; @endphp

@foreach ($file as $key=> $value)
  <tr class="file{{$value->id}}">
                <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                <td>{{$value->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$value->file}}</td>
                <td>{{$value->status}}</td> 
                <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm" data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-title="{{$value->title}}" data-status="{{$value->status}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-title="{{$value->title}}" data-status="{{$value->status}}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-title="{{$value->title}}" data-status="{{$value->status}}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </td> 
   </tr>
  @endforeach
```